# How to make authorization in Java EE to be externally recofigurable (out of war-file) and to be hot-recofigurable?

Tags: java, security, jakarta-ee

Some Java Web-framework put roles on controllers, look to example:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/company")
@RolesAllowed("ROLE_ADMIN")
public class CompanyController { ... }
```

This requires recompilation of code in order to remap roles and URLs...

Is there are any standard framework or library which allow mapping of roles and URLs out of war file and allow hot-reconfiguration (without stopping application)?

Seems that for the EE stack this requires including a custom interceptor.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604694/does-java-ee-security-model-support-acl

Comment: I have heard that they've introduced a web.xml with complete=true to suppress annotation scanning. This web.xml can be redeployed.

Comment: @JoopEggen Hm... Interesting ))

Answer (score 2):

Your given example seams the Spring security example. Please look at following tutorial. It is much helpful.

http://krams915.blogspot.com/2010/12/spring-security-3-mvc-using-simple-user.html

Comment: Is it possible to reload **spring-security.xml** without rebuilding and redeploying war file?